# Why are the buttons in my sidebar layering?

Tags: css, button

I'm trying to have my buttons below one another. However, they are layering on top of one another and are next to each other. How do I fix this problem? I would like the buttons to be below each other and not move to a second line if they are too big.

```js
// create buttons function
function myPopFunction(){
    mapGeoJSON('POPULATION',5,'YlOrRd','quantiles');}

function myServeFunction(){
    mapGeoJSON('SERVICE_CO',5,'BuPu','quantiles');}

function myGovTypeFunction(){
    mapGeoJSON('Gov Code',7,'Spectral','equal_interval');}
```

```css
body,html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 225px 1fr ;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 400px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header"
    "sidebar content dashboard"
    "sidebar content dashboard"
    "footer footer footer";
}

.sidebar {
    color: #444;
    grid-area: sidebar;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    overflow:initial; /* allows the sidebar to overflow with a scrollbar */
    
}

.sidebar-item {
    padding: 10px; /* adds inner padding */
    background: rgb(182, 199, 245); /* background color of the card */
    border: 1px solid rgb(104, 131, 253); /* border width and color */
    margin: 5px; /* outer padding */
    cursor: pointer; /* change cursor to hand on hover */
    
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #005687;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a onclick="myPopFunction()" class="dropbtn">Population</a>
            <a onclick="myServeFunction()" class="dropbtn">Service Connections</a>
            <a onclick="myGovTypeFunction()" class="dropbtn">Governance Type</a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

To manage layers, You'll have to add z-index property in the style of each button. This might require to create multiple div's for each one.

Here is Your corrected style code (sry if it's not in the code format but it is what it is, so plain text)

```
     body,html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 225px 1fr ;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 400px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header"
    "sidebar content dashboard"
    "sidebar content dashboard"
    "footer footer footer";
}

.sidebar {
    color: #444;
    grid-area: sidebar;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    overflow:initial; /* allows the sidebar to overflow with a scrollbar */
    z-index: 1
    
}

.sidebar-item {
    padding: 10px; /* adds inner padding */
    background: rgb(182, 199, 245); /* background color of the card */
    border: 1px solid rgb(104, 131, 253); /* border width and color */
    margin: 5px; /* outer padding */
    cursor: pointer; /* change cursor to hand on hover */
    z-index: 2
    
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #005687;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3
  }
```